# Diagnosing single phase 3-speed brushless AC motor

Tags: motor, troubleshooting, diagnostics, rotor-speed

The air conditioner `Family FSA-15H` has one-phase fan brushless AC motor with 3 constant speeds: High, Medium, Low. After 2 years of rare use, the fan works only on the half of designed low speed: 420 RPM instead of 980 RPM. It heats up quickly and thermal protection shuts the fan off.

[image]

I tried to find motor replacement A072 from King Post Industrial. It seems small Taiwanese company which does not deal with private users.

I tried to diagnose the motor:

- The Capacitor is 5uF as designed.
- Replacing capacitor to 6uF or to 10uF does not change anything.
- Applying 220VAC on black-blue, black-yellow, black-white wires gives the same results: slow speed and quick heating up.
- The motor rotates smoothly, applying extra grease into bearings changes nothing.
- Measuring resistance of motor coils gives strange results, marked with `?!`:
  [image]
- I tried to search for explanation for 3-constant speed brushless AC motor works but found nothing. Either results for 3-phase motors or for regulated with controller motors.

My question is:

Please, point me to reasonably clear guide to diagnose the 3-speed BLAC motor.

Or, why do I observe that strange resistances of sequentially connected coils?

Comment: Are you prepared to rewind the motor?  If not, you've diagnosed it, it's failing.  Options are buy a replacement from a different vendor, or send it to a motor repair shop.

Comment: It seems the `?!` marks which confused me are the real sign of motor failure. Isn't it? If so, I have to be creative to reach out the motor manufacturer for the replacement.